# Where to edit Script1.groovy as seen in the error?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am very new to Jenkins - I am trying to run a multibranch pipeline script on Jenkins version 2.375.1. The builds are triggered with commits and PR's filed on Github. On committing a new file or initiating a PR, Jenkins auto triggers a build but consistently stops as it hits this issue.

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 2.
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2513
```

I have added a Jenkinsfile.Jenkinsfile and Example.groovy script in my repo with this code ->

**Jenkinsfile.Jenkinsfile** (note the .Jenkinsfile extension is hidden in the repo)

```
node {
// Git checkout before load source the file
checkout scm

// To know files are checked out or not
sh '''
    ls -lhrt
'''

def rootDir = pwd()
println("Current Directory: " + rootDir)

// point to exact source file
def example = load "${rootDir}/Example.Groovy"

example.exampleMethod()
example.otherExampleMethod()
```

}

**Example.groovy** (Note the .groovy extension is hidden in repo)

```
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import hudson.EnvVars
import jenkins.model.*
jenkins = Jenkins.instance

EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty prop = jenkins.getGlobalNodeProperties().get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
EnvVars env = prop.getEnvVars()

def MY_VAR = env['MY_JENKINS_VAR']
def exampleMethod() {
    println("exampleMethod")
}

def otherExampleMethod() {
    println("otherExampleMethod")
}
return this
```

Answer (score 0):

Few days back I got to work on same thing. Not sure about editor but mine working groovy script looks like :

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'VM-narendra-build' }
    environment {
        // Global Var - If required
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            
        }
        stage('Report') {
            steps {
                
            }
        }
    }
    post {
    }
}
```